# Carla will not see Windows vst plugins

Tags: windows, wine, ubuntu-studio, vst

I am running Ubuntu Studio 20.10.  I would like to use some Windows vst plugins in my Ardour sessions.  Carla is installed.  I installed carla-bridge-win32 and carla-bridge-win64.  I also installed Q4Wine.  When I open Carla and look at the acceptable architecture, only "Native" is visible.  There are no indications that Carla will accept Windows 32 or 64 architectures.  Is there something else I should be doing so that Carla will accept the Windows plugins?  (In the settings for Carla, it appears that Carla is looking at the directories which contain the plugins.)

Answer (score 3):

Try to enable experimental features under Settings->Main and then enable plugin bridges and Wine bridges under Settings->Experimental, then refresh the plugins. Under Architecture you should now see Bridged (Wine).

Also dragging the vst file in the Rack window worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! That was the answer.  I can now see and import windows files.